# Sampling from an array in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sample

I need an idea on doing this. I'm not good at math.
Maybe it have build in function which i haven't found yet.

I have an array which consists of 2048 data.
I need to get on 250 value out of this.

I'm thinking of

```
2048/250 = 8.19
```

which means, I take value on each increment of 8 position in an array.

Is there a function to do this?

Comment: You want sampling so why not looking for an statistical library or something like that? Maybe if is a 1 time thing is an overkill

Comment: If you're taking some fixed elements, why not take the first 250?

Comment: @al3c because it would not be sampling, it would be biased

Comment: I add another way of doing it

Comment: @cutiko picking a pre-fixed set of indices is biased the same way reguardless of what indices you pick. Usually one picks random indices.

Comment: @al3c that is called pseudo-random and is used as an actual suverying method, if you take a look at my answer you will see how the random index case is also covered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of, I think the problem is to balance iterations and the randomness of the sampling.

So the naive approach

```
dataSet.indexedMapNotNull { i, data ->
    if (i % 8 == 0) data else null
}
```

That would run through all the array, so you only need 250 iterations, not `dataSet.size` iterations. So what about if we iterate 250 times and for each of those we take the 8th times of it

```
val sample = mutableListOf<DataType>()
for (i in 1..250) {
    val positionInDataSet = (i * 8) - 1 //minus one adjust the index for the size
    val case = dataSet[positionInDataSet]
    sample.add(case)
}
```

Another alternative would be to simply use copy methods from collections, but the problem is you lose your sampling

```
dataSet.subArray(0, 250)
```

Sub-array didn't sample the data in a pseudo-random way but only got the first 250 and that would be biased. The upside is usually array copies methods are a log of N.

Another option would be to randomize things even more by not getting data each 8 but a random position until we hit our desired sample size.

```
val sample = mutableSetOf<DataType>()

while (sample.size != 250) {
    val randomPosition = Random.nextInt(0, dataSet.size)
    val randomSelection = dataSet[randomPosition]
    sample.add(randomeSelection)

}
```

Here we use a set, because a `Set` guarantee unique elements, so you have completely random 250 elements from your data set. The problem with this is that randomness on the position could make the same `randomPosition` more than once, so you iterate on the data set more than 250 times, this could even be factorial which in larger data sets it would happen and is considered the lowest performance.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion. Need to get what are you saying first :)

Comment: You need to obtain 250 values from the data set, those values have to be obtained through all the data set, not just the from 0 to 250, so we define a randomize way to do so, in this case if each 8, because that is 2048 divided by 250. So then instead of iterating the data set each time and getting that data if is a position divisible by 8, we only iterate 250 times wich is what we need.

Comment: i prefer the second option which not randomize it. just take the increment of 8. thanks a lot